# How to prove energy of a path graph increases with its increasing path weight?

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, symmetric-matrices

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, if its adjacency matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq . . . \geq \lambda_n$ then the energy is defined as:
$$\mathcal{E}(G) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} |\lambda_i|.$$

By trials and errors experimentation, with a simple undirected edge weighted  path T, it seems that the energy of $T$., or $\mathcal{E}(T)$ proportionally increases with increasing weight of $T$  (but doesn't seem to hold in general graph).

> How to prove that $\mathcal{E}(T)$ increases with increasing weight of $T$?

Comment: You mean if you multiply all the weights together by a fixed positive constant $c$, the energy is multiplied by $kc$ for some positive constant $k$? If so, that's trivial since $\lambda_i$ becomes $c \lambda_i$ so the energy $\mathcal{E}$ becomes $c\mathcal{E}$.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? Can you precisely state what you wish to prove?

Comment: In case of multiplying the weights by a fixed constant, energy is also multiplied by the same constant. In this case, the proof seems to be trivial.

Comment: @Ian For instance, consider a path $T$ of length 2. Let $T_1$ represents $T$ when its edge labels are $2$ and $3$, and let $T_2$ represents $T$ when its edge labels are $5$ and $7$, then energy of $T_2$ is greater than that of $T_1$, etc.

Comment: So you want to ask whether $\frac{\partial \mathcal{E}}{\partial w_i}$ is always positive? It doesn't seem that you want to ask about proportionality per se.

Comment: @Ian yes,  that ratio seems to be less than or equal to one.